# How can I best photograph the Infinity Mirrors exhibit by Yayoi Kusama?

Tags: camera-settings, shooting-technique, reflection, art, darkness

I'd like to take pictures of [Yayoi Kusama's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yayoi_Kusama) exhibit, [The Infinity Mirrors](https://hirshhorn.si.edu/kusama/infinity-rooms/). This exhibit a collection of mirrored rooms, usually darkly lit.

What are some tips on photographing in dark, mirrored rooms? Should I use a tripod? Often, museums don't allow tripods. If that's the case when I visit, what should I do?

Here are some photos others have taken of the Infinity Mirrors exhibit:

[image: Yayoi Kusama Infinity Room from Wikimedia Commons]
<sup>[*Yayoi Kusama Infinity Room*](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Yayoi_Kusama_Infinity_Room.jpg), from Wikimedia Commons, by Helsinki Art Museum, The Broad. [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.en)</sup>

[image: Yayoi Kusama, Infinity Dots Mirrored Room, 1996]
<sup>[*Yayoi Kusama, Infinity Dots Mirrored Room, 1996*](https://www.flickr.com/photos/sixteen-miles/3742901291), by [Andrew Russeth](https://www.flickr.com/photos/sixteen-miles/). [CC BY-SA 2.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/)</sup>

[image: All the Eternal Love I Have for the Pumpkins]
<sup>[*Yayoi Kusama's Infinity Mirrored Room 'All the Eternal Love I Have for the Pumpkins'*](https://www.flickr.com/photos/22711505@N05/33616487770), by [Ron Cogswell](https://www.flickr.com/photos/22711505@N05/). [CC BY-SA 2.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/)</sup>

[image: “Vision is a subtractive process..."]
<sup>[*“Vision is a subtractive process..."*](https://www.flickr.com/photos/anokarina/33783976350), by [anokarina](https://www.flickr.com/photos/anokarina/). [CC BY-SA 2.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

No Flash 
Tripod (if permitted), possibly low position (for mushroom like structure)
Relatively low ISO (100-400)
... For a pseudo macro shot... Showing the infinite mushroom behind.

... Or, for the stars, a "zoom while you shoot" effect, that will look like the Tron movie...

Anything good ?

Answer (score 1):

> What are some tips on photographing in dark, mirrored rooms? Should I use a tripod? Often, museums don't allow tripods. If that's the case when I visit, what should I do?

One of those photos is taken with an iPhone 7, another one with a dSLR using iso 1600. I'd say go with the biggest sensor you have, and crank up the ISO to get a good handholding shutter speed, and make sure you do not underexpose.  Go handheld. Practice [your handholding technique](https://digital-photography-school.com/how-to-hold-a-digital-camera/). Go research techniques that use a string or the camera strap to increase stability. Learn about [different camera holds](http://blog.joemcnally.com/2008/03/10/da-grip/).

Figure out how to [focus accurately in low light](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18507/how-can-i-focus-in-very-low-light-with-my-canon-60d).

And since this is a *mirrored* exhibit, consider what you're wearing. :)

When shooting in a well-known museum, you can typically go to the museum's website and find their photography policy before heading out there with a tripod strapped to your bag. Easy enough to find out if you can use one or not ahead of time. The [Smithsonian website visitor tips page](https://www.si.edu/visit/tips) says (bold mine):

> **Photography**
>
> The Smithsonian permits still and video photography for noncommercial use only in its museums and exhibitions, unless otherwise posted.
>
> For the safety of our visitors and collections, **the Smithsonian prohibits the use of tripods, monopods, or selfie sticks in our museums and gardens**. This is a preventive measure to protect visitors and objects, especially during crowded conditions. We encourage museum visitors to take selfies and share their experiences—and leave the selfie sticks in their bags.
>
> Working members of the media who need to use a tripod or monopod must obtain permission from the museum's Public Affairs Office and must be escorted by a museum staff member while in the building or garden.

Comment: Another explanation of hand holding technique, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_a6XaQ16aaE